# Loading an external script at suite level in SoapUI

Tags: testing, groovy, automation

currently i am working on SoapUI for testing. Can anyone tell how can i load an external script at testsuite level so that i don't have to load it in each test step. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does anyone got any answer??

Comment: @Vidusha, I think i am looking for the same kind of answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43138679/execute-jdbc-teststep-using-groovy-in-soapui

Comment: @luckyvasul you can use that external script as a library of SoapUI, you can use this link to configure http://readyapi.smartbear.com/features/scripts/library#_ga=1.242495878.547736580.1479705165